# Не работает удаленный доступ. MySQL server has gone away, code 2006

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Сайт на Laravel. Есть удаленное подключение в mysql бд на windows, которое исправно работает

```
'mysqlremote' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '11.112.91.12',
        'database'  => 'test',
        'username'  => 'root3',
        'password'  => '',
        'port' => '3306',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
    ]
```

Поставили новый сервер, на котором надо организовать это же подключение, но с новым портом. Тот же айпи, **новый порт 34567**, который прописан в mysql, привилегии юзеру даны, брандмауэр отключен. Выдает ошибку:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" {code: "2006 Ошибка
>   коннекта с БД"}

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте эту строчку в файле my.cnf:

`max_allowed_packet=64M`

Это полезно, когда столбцы имеют большие значения, которые вызывают проблемы, вы можете найти объяснение [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-max-allowed-packet.html)

> В Windows этот файл находится по адресу: «C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 (версия MySQL)»
>
> В Linux (Ubuntu): / etc / mysql

Comment: Abdullah Hafizov, спасибо за совет, но не помогло, бд таже, поменялся только порт((

Comment: я тут думаю может неправильно настроен роутер, но это подскажет только сисадмин

Comment: @игорь88, а пробовал ставить 
`wait_timeout= 6000` в файле my.cnf

Comment: у меня версия 5.5 там есть только my.ini в котором этой настройки нет )

Comment: @игорь88 в `Linux это my.cnf`, а в `Windows my.ini`, добавь те значения которые были наверху в `my.ini` и перезагрузи свой сервер

Comment: Abdullah Hafizov, проблема была в настйроке роутера, сисадмин разобрался и тебе спасибо за помощь